# How to add space between border line and menu item

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add space between a bottom border line and my `<li>` item but no luck.

My code:

```
<div class="menuwrap">
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Query</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Reports</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS styles:

```css
.menu {
    color: #000;
    background: #FFF;
}
.menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 40px;
    margin-top: 90px;
}
.menu li {
    float:left;
    margin-left:10px;
}
.menu li a:hover {
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    font-size: xx-large;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    border-spacing: 20px;
}
.menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: large;
}
.menuwrap {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

I tried couple of different things, but nothing worked so far. border-spacing is not doing what I want. I tried padding-bottom and that also didn't work. Can someone tell me how to achieve that? I want a space between the "li" item and its border-bottom.

Comment: Do you want the space always, or just on hover?

Comment: Padding bottom works for pushing borders down in my tests - can you create a JSFiddle and explain exactly what you're trying to achieve. What code did you try and in what way is it wrong

Comment: I want it just on hover.

Comment: Smokey, like in this example http://jsfiddle.net/VZCrq/8/  it works fine if it is on the menu li but it doesn't work if i create padding-bottom on the a:hover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a padding-bottom or margin-bottom seems to be working.

```css
li:hover{
   padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

> Here's a [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dwJRP/3/)

or

```css
li:hover{
   margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

> Here's a [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dwJRP/2/)

**Update**: After reading your comment and having a look at the fiddle you provided, I've created one which does what you are trying to do. It's different from the code you provided but it's easier to read and you can modify it according to your needs

```css
.menu{
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menu li{
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  zoom: 1;
  margin: 10px;
}

.menu li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.menu li a:hover{
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/VF2Dq/)

Comment: It is my mistake that I didn't specify that the problem arise when I use it with a:hover

Answer (score 0):

I guess you didn't give your styles. `padding-bottom` works. Please check http://jsfiddle.net/VZCrq/8/